# Getting different results each time I run FFT with Processing and Beads

Tags: java, processing, signal-processing, fft

I am using Processing 3 with the Beads library in order to analyse a number of samples but each time I run the analysis on the same data, I get very different results. Here's the sample and analysis setup:

```
import beads.*;
import org.jaudiolibs.beads.*;

AudioContext ac;
GranularSamplePlayer sample;
Gain gain;

ShortFrameSegmenter sfs;
FFT fft;
PowerSpectrum ps;
Frequency f;
SpectralPeaks sp;
float[][] meanHarmonics;

int numPeaks = 6;

void setup() {
  size(1600, 900);
  ac = new AudioContext();
  ac.start();
  println(dataPath("") + "1.wav");
  sample = new GranularSamplePlayer(ac, SampleManager.sample(dataPath("") + "\\1.wav"));
  
  gain = new Gain(ac, 1, 1);
  
  // input chaining
  gain.addInput(sample);
  ac.out.addInput(gain);
  
  // setup analysis
  // break audio into more manageable chunks
  sfs = new ShortFrameSegmenter(ac);
  sfs.addInput(sample);
  
  // fast fourier transform to analyse the harmonic spectrum
  fft = new FFT();
  sfs.addListener(fft);
  
  // PowerSpectrum turns the raw FFT output into proper audio data.
  ps = new PowerSpectrum();
  fft.addListener(ps);
  
  // Frequency tries to determine the strongest frequency in the wave
  // which is the fundamental that determines the pitch of the sound
  f = new Frequency(44100.0f);
  ps.addListener(f);
  
  // Listens for harmonics
  sp = new SpectralPeaks(ac, numPeaks);
  ps.addListener(sp);
  
  meanHarmonics = new float[numPeaks][2];
  
  // initialise meanHarmonics
  for(int i = 0; i < numPeaks; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      meanHarmonics[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
  
  ac.out.addDependent(sfs);
  
  int startTime = millis();
  int loops = 0;
  float meanFrequency = 0.0;
  while(millis() - startTime < 1500) {
    loops++;
      if(loops == 1) {
       sample.start(0); 
      }
      Float inputFrequency = f.getFeatures();
      if(inputFrequency != null) {
        meanFrequency += inputFrequency;
      }
      float[][] harmonics = sp.getFeatures();
      if(harmonics != null) {
        for(int feature = 0; feature < numPeaks; feature++) {
         // harmonic must be in human audible range
         // and its amplitude must be large enough to be audible
         if(harmonics[feature][0] < 20000.0 && harmonics[feature][1] > 0.01) {
          // average out the frequencies
          meanHarmonics[feature][0] += harmonics[feature][0];
          // average out the amplitudes
          meanHarmonics[feature][1] += harmonics[feature][1]; 
         }
        }
      }
    }
    float maxAmp = 0.0;
    float freq = 0.0;
    sample.pause(true);
    meanFrequency /= loops;
    println(meanFrequency);
    for(int feature = 0; feature < numPeaks; feature++) {
      meanHarmonics[feature][0] /= loops;
      meanHarmonics[feature][1] /= loops;
      if(meanHarmonics[feature][1] > maxAmp) {
        freq = meanHarmonics[feature][0];
        maxAmp = meanHarmonics[feature][1];
      }
      println(meanHarmonics[feature][0] + " " + meanHarmonics[feature][1]);
    }
    println(freq + " " + meanFrequency);
    println();
}
```

I run FFT for a set amount of time during which I sum the frequency returned by the Frequency object and the SpectralPeaks features.
At the end I divide accumulated frequencies and amplitudes to obtain the means. I also try to find the fundamental frequency in the SpectralPeaks array by finding the frequency with the largest amplitude.
But every time I run my program I get a different result, both from SpectralPeaks and Frequency(and their values also differ from each other).
Here are some example values:

1st run:

> Spectral Peaks features:
>
> 914.84863 0.040409338
>
> 844.96295 0.033234257
>
> 816.0808 0.027509697
>
> 664.9141 0.022158746
>
> 633.3232 0.019597264
>
> 501.93716 0.01606628
>
> Spectral Peaks fundamental: 914.84863
>
> Frequency: 1028.1572

2nd run, same sample:

> Spectral Peaks features:
>
> 1023.4123 0.03913592
>
> 1109.2562 0.031178929
>
> 967.0786 0.026673868
>
> 721.2698 0.021666735
>
> 629.9294 0.018046249
>
> 480.82416 0.014858524
>
> Spectral Peaks fundamental: 1023.4123
>
> Frequency: 1069.3387

Also, the value returned by Frequency is often NaN, I don't understand why that is.

Comment: you dont have a random thing do you ?? oh ok you do

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: in panGlide you have this  random.nextFloat()  your input changes each time

Comment: Thanks, I changed that to be constant but I still get different values and NaNs.

Comment: still there may be other random things - as for Nan its probably going out of bounds - somewhere - you dont show all the code so one cannt tell - I dnt know all these libraries but your processing might cause it - e.g. division by 0

Comment: Please [debug your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) and narrow your problem down to a [mcve]. You have at least one call to a random function in your code, which is going to give you different results. But it's going to be very hard to help you until you narrow your problem down to a [mcve].

Comment: I've edited my code down to an MCV, sorry for the mess before. I've also removed all random function calls. I don't think I can provide the sample I'm using but it's a WAV file of around 14 seconds. The algorithm still returns different values every time and NaNs from the Frequency object.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code returns different values is because it is sampling and analyzing the audio at different moments. Once you start playing the audio, you have no control when `Float inputFrequency = f.getFeatures();` gets executed. 
A better approach is not to use `millis()` and replace the `while` loop with a `for loop`, and use `ac.runForMillisecondsNonRealTime()`. This way you get know exactly that you performing the analysis for a 1500 milliseconds.

```
  //while(millis() - startTime < 1500) {
  for(int i = 0; i < numPeaks; i++) {
      ac.runForNMillisecondsNonRealTime(1500/numPeaks);      
      Float inputFrequency = f.getFeatures();
      if(inputFrequency != null) {
        meanFrequency += inputFrequency;
      }
      float[][] harmonics = sp.getFeatures();
      if(harmonics != null) {
        for(int feature = 0; feature < numPeaks; feature++) {
         // harmonic must be in human audible range
         // and its amplitude must be large enough to be audible
         if(harmonics[feature][0] < 20000.0 && harmonics[feature][1] > 0.01) {
          // average out the frequencies
          meanHarmonics[feature][0] += harmonics[feature][0];
          // average out the amplitudes
          meanHarmonics[feature][1] += harmonics[feature][1]; 
         }
        }
      }
    }
```